# Problems when constructing a Fractal Tree

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to use what I learned in the this [fractal tutorial](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/constructing-a-fractal/) to make something I can use for my own project. I want to a script that can generate trees in Unity. I feel I've made a lot of progress, but have hit a wall.

The way I've set up the script is so that it scales the branches according to two parameters:

- a) a publich 'childScale' variable.
- b) the amount of branches sprouting from the previous branch.

The biggest problem has been that, when children are parented to a non-uniform-scale object, they become distorted in unintended ways. To bypass, I've made the prefab instances (which are 1, 1, 1 by default) children of other GameObjects. These GameObjects are also parents to other GameObjects that contain other prefab instances. This is problematic because the scaling principle of a fractal necessitates a continuous inheritance of scale from the parent, but the child prefab instances never pass anything along. So I end up having to adjust the proportions of the prefab instances to what they would be if they could inherit directly from one another. The below script 'works' because of the exponential modifier (middle of Start(), after 'else'), but only if all branches have the same amount of offshoots, i.e. only if the public min and max Branch Density variables are the same integer.

**To summarize, I have two problems that I'd like your input on.**

- The main problem: How can I maintain the scaling integrity of the fractal principle despite the lack of a continous hierarchy while allowing for non-uniformity in the overall form of the tree?
- A secondary problem, by far, is that my 'thicknessScaler' variable makes my branches too thin, especially the more there are. Right now it just divides 1 by the amount of offshoots, so I'd need one that doesn't shave off quite as much.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TreeFractal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] branches; // the last branch is pointed, while all the others are rounded
    public int maxDepth;
    public float childScale; 
    public float maxTwist; // OFF temporarily
    public Vector3 baseBranchSize; // proportions of instantiated prefab
    public int minBranchDensity; // amount of offshoots per node, randomized
    public int maxBranchDensity; 
    public float branchTilt;

    private int depth;
    private int branchDensity;
    private GameObject branch;
    private GameObject instance;
    private TreeFractal grandparent;
    private float displace;
    private float thicknessScaler = 1;
    private float parentDensity;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (depth < maxDepth)
            branch = branches[0];
        else
            branch = branches[1];

        instance = Instantiate(branch); 

        instance.transform.parent = transform; // prefabs (non-uniform proportions) are made the children of uniform-scaled Game Objects.

        if (depth == 0)
        {
            displace = baseBranchSize.y;
            instance.transform.localScale = baseBranchSize;
        }

        else //Multiplication by density^depth is to make up for the shrinking game objects, as the prefab instances do not pass on their scale
            //while the GameObjects do. This only works when all 'depths' of the tree have the same amount of offshoots.
            //Because the GameObject must remain uniform, all scaling of the y axis must occur in the prefab instance.
        {
            displace = baseBranchSize.y * Mathf.Pow(parentDensity, depth);
            //if (depth == 2)3
                print(baseBranchSize.y * Mathf.Pow(parentDensity, depth));
            instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3
            (
                baseBranchSize.x,
                baseBranchSize.y  * Mathf.Pow(parentDensity, depth),
                baseBranchSize.z
            );
        }

        instance.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 1f * (displace / 2), 0f); //prefab instance pivots at one end of the GameObject, for rotations.
        instance.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);

        transform.Rotate(Random.Range(-maxTwist * ((float)(depth + 1)/ maxDepth), maxTwist * ((float)(depth + 1) / maxDepth)), 0f, 0f);
        //increases the potential randomized twist more, the smaller the branches get.

        if (depth < maxDepth)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CreateChildren());
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator CreateChildren()
    {
        branchDensity = Random.Range(minBranchDensity, maxBranchDensity + 1);


        for (int i = 0; i < branchDensity; i++)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f));

            Quaternion quaternion = BranchRotater(branchDensity, i); 

            new GameObject("Fractal Child").AddComponent<TreeFractal>().
            Initialize(this, i, quaternion);

        }

    }

    private Quaternion BranchRotater (int density, int childIndex) //returns the rotation of the branch depending on the index and amount of branches.
    {
        Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler
            (0f,
            (360 / density) * childIndex,
            branchTilt
            );
        return quaternion;
    }

    private void Initialize(TreeFractal parent, int childIndex, Quaternion quaternion)
    {
        branches = parent.branches; 
        branchTilt = parent.branchTilt;
        maxDepth = parent.maxDepth; 
        depth = parent.depth + 1;
        baseBranchSize = parent.baseBranchSize;
        maxTwist = parent.maxTwist; 
        transform.parent = parent.transform;
        childScale = parent.childScale;
        minBranchDensity = parent.minBranchDensity;
        maxBranchDensity = parent.maxBranchDensity;
        thicknessScaler = 1f / parent.branchDensity; // I need a better equation here. This scaler is too small.
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one * childScale * thicknessScaler; // reproportions all 3 axes of child GameObject so that
            //the child remains of uniform scale. This must then be compensated for in the scaling of said object's child-prefab. 
        parentDensity = parent.branchDensity;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.up * parent.displace; //positions child relative to its parent
        transform.localRotation = quaternion;


    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to have a look at L-Systems

Comment: For now, I was hoping to apply knowledge from tutorials, but that looks very interesting and I'll look into it in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Are you talking about this: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/l-systems-for-unity-free-script-included.272416/

I'm going to contact the thread-maker since that topic is a few years old.

Comment: Yes I ment something of that kind. For a general overview see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system)

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Btw, if I want code reviewed that is functional, but related to Unity (i.e. not in its native environment), is it better to post here or on codereview?

Comment: Code reviews should generally go to codeReview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your prefab like this you can apply the parent-to-child scale at the root node of the prefab and the nonuniform at the subnode. If you now attach the child's root to the root node only the uniform scale will carry over.

```
prefab:
 [root]
   |--->[non-uni]
   |        |---> mesh
   .
   .
   [childRoot]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that is different from what I've been trying to do. Could you elaborate on the implementation?

Comment: As an added note: If, instead of applying both the thickness scaler and child scaler to the empty game object and and reversing the changes to the y axis, as above, I apply only the child scaler to the game object and reserved the thickness scaler for the child prefab, the thickness scaler is not inherited and the branches become too thick in proportion to the parent branch.

Comment: It's different in that you separate the uniform from the non-uniform scale. You will still have to propagate the thickness scale downwards. for example by having a MonoBehaviour on the root node that gives the value to its children.

Comment: Ah, of course. I've changed the initiate function to have thicknessScaler = parent.thicknessScaler / parent.branchDensity;
That passes along the value along nicely.

Thanks for your help!